# CherryPy post file request to Flask resulting file object issue

Tags: python, file, flask, python-requests, cherrypy

The main theme of this work is to post request a file from cherry py to flask and upload it but the file object gets empty on flask end:

Cherry Py code :

```
files = {'upload_file' : files_raw_data[i]}
values = {'file_path': full_upload_path}
response = requests.post(file_storage_url, files=files, data=values)
```

`Files Object is : <cherrypy._cpreqbody.Part object at 0x7f0d9e070400>`

File object at this point is correct and working fine

Flask end :

```
@app.route('/upload_file', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    file = request.files['upload_file']
```

`Files Object is : <FileStorage: 'files' (None)>`

File object gets empty on flask end

Comment: You should show the CherryPy handler code. What you labeled as CherryPy just includes `requests` code which is a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

I never use Cherry Py, but you can put a `print(request.files)` or a `print(request.__dict__)` to verify if the file is sent correctly.

```
@app.route('/upload_file', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    print(request.files)
    print(request.__dict__)
```

maybe cherrypy have other patter to send files

Comment: I am getting the other post data but file object is assigned with <FileStorage: 'files' (None)>